# Running a download option without affecting current page process

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have an export option on which click of a button, a download process starts and let the user download the excel sheet, which I have created using **phpspreadsheet**,The problem is when I click on download, the process goes to the controller and starts executing the function, when this happens the page just runs with a loader loading till the function execute. I can't click on another page as it will stop the function. I have to wait till the download option becomes shown,This would take around a minute, I need the process run in background without affecting the current process, I have tried to run the process on a new tab but what happens is when a new tab opens, the process is loading and my current page is still loading till the function gets completed.

```
    <button class="btn btn-primary shadow-primary px-5" onclick="newtab()">Export</button>

<script>
 window.open('<?php echo base_url() ?>Expensetracker/export');
</script>
```

Comment: You're probably using a framework. Which one?

Comment: Codeigniter framework @KIKOSoftware